# Limitar Caracteres en acrobat

Tags: javascript

> necesito limitar la cantidad de caracteres que se puedan ingresar en un campo de texto en adobe acrobat

```js
var campoTexto = this.getField('Text90');
var valor = campoTexto.value;
 if (valor.length == 3 || valor.length > 7) {
       app.alert('Error');
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Es incorrecta la validación. Cuantos caracteres deseas limitar?